# Why my face is missing when I export fbx from Blender to Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, .fbx

I am exporting .fbx to Unity 3D from Blender 3d but when I see the object in Unity it has a face missing. Can anyone help me fix?

[image: face missing]

Thank you,
Waqas

Comment: Most likely this this is a normals issue.
Go into blenders edit mode, select the problem face and press CTRL+SHIFT+N to flip the normals.

Comment: I tried and it makes the other ones go away and then those ones are now transparent.

Comment: You should only select the face that's causing the issue, then flip the normals. Also I'd recommend to remove all the doubles beforehand just in case they're causing problems as well. shortcut menu while in edit mode 'W'.

Comment: Nope, I removed doubles (0 ver removed) and then I selected just the face which was causing problem and exported again but it's the same. I will try to look in further and update. Thanks

Comment: Okay, it worked. My mistake there is a vertex that was overlapped on the mesh and then I flipped normals and it worked! Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to select problematic faces and then flip the normals.

To flip normals, open Blender in *Edit Mode* select problematic faces and go to *Mesh > Normals > Flip*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone searching it as me... sometime polygons not just flipped but totally disappear after export. its because of complexity of polygon itself that Unity cut off due to optimization. To make it visible in Unity you just need to triangulate that invisible polygon (Ctrl+T in Blender) that make it "simple" and visible in Unity.