# Export fbx file from blender to Unity, then I got missing faces

Tags: faces, normals, unity

I exported 3d model to Unity that I made using Blender. But I realized some faces are missing in unity. And Im not talking about that normal of missing faces are wrong. Those are literally missing.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there are 2 selcted faces in these 2 pictures. Those faces are missing faces in unity, and material of both are different. And another thing that makes me confusing is only those two faces are missing, I mean, if material of the faces are wrong, then other faces using same material have to be missing too, right? But other faces are not missing! And another thing is these faces can be shown in Blender but not in Unity.

And you might think then why im thinking faces are missing, not wrong normal.
There are 2 reasons.

1. if I change remove those material in right material slot in mesh renderer of unity, other faces get pink color, but those 2 faces are still showing nothing.
2. There are cars going below the faces.
   [image]

Can you see those Red Line area? the turquious green , blue , yellow cubes are cars(just demo design) and if there is a face and i just cant see that, then i could click the face, right? But if i click the face, unity editor show me inspector of the car, not the face.

So I dont know how but, faces are missing in unity but not in blender. And I hope this is matter of normals so i can fix it easily

**I checked face orientation too....
[image]

Answer (score 0):

God, I really hate Unity.
Found the answer. Unity cant read well n-gon face. So I triangulated missing faces and now i can see well in Unity. Thanks to the @Constantine M in the link below( I cant comment on his answer cause i dont have enough reputation for comment.)

[Why my face is missing when I export fbx from Blender to Unity 3D?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78878/why-my-face-is-missing-when-i-export-fbx-from-blender-to-unity-3d)

Comment: @AllenSimpson Hello. sorry but I dont know why you are thinking im using this site as forum, I just posted my issue and I found answer, so I just answered my own question just in case if anybody like me can find answer if they see my post. And as I said, my reputation isnt enough for comment and vote, so I cannot thanks to the person in link

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was in the queue.  I thought you were commenting on another answer, will remove.